# split and generate columns automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

df

```
fruit                want_split
apple    colour:red, like:yes, favourite:no
banana   colour:yellow, like:yes, favourite:no
pear     colour:green, like:yes, favourite:yes
```

Is there a way to split by the comma and then automatically generate column names, rather than manually?
Expected Output:

```
fruit                want_split                  colour      like    favourite
apple    colour:red, like:yes, favourite:no     red        yes       no
banana   colour:yellow, like:yes, favourite:no  yellow     yes       no
pear     colour:green, like:yes, favourite:yes  green      yes       yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pivot / `unstack` and `join` after `str.split` and `explode`:

```
u = df['want_split'].str.split(",").explode().str.split(":",expand=True)
out = df.join(u.set_index(0,append=True)[1].unstack())
```

---

```
print(out)

     type                             want_split  favourite  like  colour
0   apple     colour:red, like:yes, favourite:no         no   yes     red
1  banana  colour:yellow, like:yes, favourite:no         no   yes  yellow
2    pear  colour:green, like:yes, favourite:yes        yes   yes   green
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract capture group in the `regex` pattern as columns in dataframe.

```
c = ['colour','like','favourite']
df[c] = df['want_split'].str.extractall(r':([^,]+)')[0].unstack()
```

Alternatively you can try [`.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df[c] = df['want_split'].str.findall(r':([^,]+)').tolist()
```

---

```
    fruit                             want_split  colour like favourite
0   apple     colour:red, like:yes, favourite:no     red  yes        no
1  banana  colour:yellow, like:yes, favourite:no  yellow  yes        no
2    pear  colour:green, like:yes, favourite:yes   green  yes       yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `split` with `dict` , then create the additional column

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.want_split.map(lambda s : dict(item.split(":") for item in s.split(", "))).tolist(),index=df.index))
    fruit                           want_split  colour like favourite
0   apple     colour:red,like:yes,favourite:no     red  yes        no
1  banana  colour:yellow,like:yes,favourite:no  yellow  yes        no
2    pear  colour:green,like:yes,favourite:yes   green  yes       yes
```